# Macbook: How to enable switching applications with command+tab after switching control and command?

Tags: macbook-pro, shortcut, application-switcher

I'm trying to have the same keys as my windows (I use both windows & mac).
The only thing I'm not able to achieve is switching applications with command & tab.

- I've switched command & control in the modifier keys
- I've tried downloading HyperSwitch which is an application for just that, but the Macbook's application switcher has more application that the HyperSwitch (It doesn't catch everything)
- I've tried to add custom shortcut at: System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> App Shortcuts, but I don't know what is the exact name of this action. I've tried "Switch application", "Application switcher", and more.

I'm sure that some solution exists. What am I missing? Thanks